# How to recover a deleted git repo

Tags: github, netlify

Unfortunately, I accidentally deleted a git repo that I needed without knowing it and it's been more than 3 months so I couldn't recover it in Github.
The website is published on Netlify at the moment. So I'm hoping to see if there's a way to recover the files from Netlify or other methods.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try this to download the deployed code from netlify - https://answers.netlify.com/t/can-i-download-my-website/3622/2

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to recover a non-organizational repo. Now, Just clone your project from Netlify

> Read this
> [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/restoring-a-deleted-repository)

Comment: i don't understand, what's fr?

Comment: Just setup the project locally from Netlify.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).